# Authentication is required for gems.contribsys.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

> Authentication is required for gems.contribsys.com. Please supply credentials for this source. You can do this by running:  bundle config gems.contribsys.com username:password

Whenever I try to do bundle install I use to get this error. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: same issue with my setup as well, but this is a bug/service issue

Comment: related to: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2818?

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to get the correct credentials.  For example, we use Sidekiq and I had to get the correct username and password.  After that I ran something like

`$ bundle config gems.contribsys.com foo:bar`

Try running `$ bundle config gems.contribsys.com username:password` with the appropriate username and password.

Comment: You probably mean sidekiq pro, when you buy a license they provide you with the username and password.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this for a repo I forked.  The source repo was using sidekiq-pro.  To fix it, I edited the Gemfile and changed...

FROM the paid version

```
source 'https://gems.contribsys.com/' do
  gem 'sidekiq-pro'
end
gem 'sidekiq'
```

TO the free version

```
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 5.2'
```